# compiling with Bibtex a .bst file, error "the compiler is having troubles understanding

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, compilation-error

I am trying to use for my bibliography a style from the Nature mag. However, it doesn't compile. I have made a minimal example, I am using the packages subfolders and bibunits. I mention it because on a project that doesn't have that structure I have no problem. I am quite new TEX so I can't really debug this.

Here is the minimal example

https://www.overleaf.com/read/zqhtgdgxhykp

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you contacted the Overleaf help team?

Comment: THE MWE fails to load the `jabbrv.sty` where the `\JournalTitle` command is defined.

Comment: Please don't direct us to Overleaf projects which may cease to exist at some point in the future.  Instead, post the minimal example here.

Comment: Yes I have asked the support it seems it's indeed due to how they handle it on their side. I am not knowledgeable enough to give you the technical explanation. But I changed my bilbiography style to something that compiles. 
Thank you.